# services.yml syntax error? Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig, yaml

There must be a syntax error in this YML file. Because for example, as it currently is I get this error:

```
The function "appPendingTasks" does not exist in ::layout.html.twig at line 64
```

But then if I delete the `twig.extension.show.responses` block, it works fine! (Except for when I load the page that requires show.responses, which obviously doesn't work).

Can anyone see anything wrong with this?

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value

services:
    twig.extension.pending.tasks:
      class: MyApp\TaskBundle\Extensions\PendingTasksExtension
      arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
      tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
    twig.extension.show.responses:
      class: MyApp\TaskBundle\Extensions\ShowResponsesExtension
      arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
      tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
    twig.extension.show.question:
      class: MyApp\TaskBundle\Extensions\ShowQuestionExtension
      arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
      tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: The syntax of the service definition is correct, check the difference in the two class:  PendingTasksExtension and ShowResponsesExtension. I suppose the have the same name defined in the getName function. As other try you can invert the sequence of the service definition. I expect that the error now is to the other function. Hope this help.

Comment: You're a legend. That indeed was the problem. If you make that the answer I can mark it as correct? Thanks

Comment: thanks @b85411 is only i make this and some others mistake too!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the service definition is correct, check the difference in the two class: `PendingTasksExtension` and `ShowResponsesExtension`.

I suppose the have the **same name** defined in the `getName` function.

As other try you can invert the sequence of the service definition: I expect that the error now is to the other function.

Hope this help